# Why am I getting this suggestion? What does it even mean?

Tags: user-interface

After I finished writing the following code snippet

```
With[{values = {-3, 0.3, -0.03, -0.003, 0.003, 0.03, 0.3, 3}},
 Grid[
  Partition[
   Table[
    Block[{b = value},
     Plot[
      b t,
      {t, 0, 100},
      PlotLabel -> Row[{HoldForm[b] -> b}]
      ]
     ], {value, values}], 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]]]
```

I realized that `b` in `HoldForm` (at `PlotLabel -> Row[{HoldForm[b] -> b}]`) was highlighted in red and hovering the cursor on top of it produces a tool tip with the text: "*b in HoldForm occurs where it is probably not going to be evaluated before going out of scope*".

[image]
A the end of the tool tiop, there is an info button that, when pressed, opens up the documentation of `HoldForm`.

Can somebody, please, explain to me why am I getting this behavior?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. You gave a temporary value to `b`, then used `b` in a context where it won't be evaluated. Minimal example (which you should construct yourself next time): `Block[{b = 1}, HoldForm[b]]`. This is a warning, not an error. It is up to you to decide whether it is relevant (here it's clearly not).

Comment: Take a look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/5478

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a Mathemmatica issue, but a misunderstanding of a warning message by the OP.

Comment: The code editor doesn't know anything about semantics. It only knows about syntax. Just ignore the warning.

Comment: a workaround (instead of ignoring the error) may be to do `bname = HoldForm[b];` before the `Block`, then do `PlotLabel -> Row[{bname -> b}]`